# awk: combine expressions by logical OR

Tags: awk

I want combine (logical OR) two awk expressions. Seperatly both work fine. The first expression prints the line right before the search term. The second expression just prints the line that contains a special character. If I combine bothe expression by a OR operator I get the error '

> ^ unexpected newline or end of string

'

```
awk '(({$0~/\*/; print a; a=$0}) || (/\→/))' file.txt
```

file.txt looks like this:

```
foo
*
bla
bla
bar→
bar→
foo
*
bla
bla
bar→
foo
*
bla
bar→
bar→
```

Expected result:

```
foo
bar→
bar→
foo
bar→
foo
bar→
bar→
```

Comment: What do you mean with "printing the line right before the search term"? All I see in the example is lines with either an asterisk or the →, so I'm not sure how lines before a match come to this?

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to the line break in the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the note about printing the *previous* line when seeing an asterisk, and the *current* line when seeing a `→`:

```
awk '/\*/ {print prev} /\→/ {print} {prev=$0}' file.txt
```

`/pattern/ {action}` is short for `$0 ~ /pattern/ {action}`. The first action prints the variable `prev` if there is an asterisk on the line, the second prints the current line if there is an arrow, and finally, we *unconditionally* save the current line to `prev`, so that it's available for printing if the next line matches.

Comment: Seems almost identical to my answer....

Comment: Seem so, but this one works exactly! 'print prev' did it! Great!

Comment: @user3072843 You really see any difference from my answer? It is up to you to accept the solution you like, but claiming that my proposal is different and not working seems not valid.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, Sorry, I didn't notice yours. I don't think there are too many different ways to implement this, though, so identical solutions will crop up.

Comment: Ok man, things like that can happen. No worries.

Comment: Clarity for clarity's sake. And if @user3072843, wants to move the tick mark to George, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your requirements, you describe **two** different expressions for **two different jobs**.
You say :

```
First expression prints the line right before the search term
Second expression just prints the line that contains a special character
```

Meaning that those two expressions can NOT be combined in OR. You combine with OR expressions that will perform the same action.

As a result the correct answer according to your wording is :

```
$ awk '/\*/{print a}{a=$0}/\→/' <<<"$a"
foo
bar→
bar→
foo
bar→
foo
bar→
bar→
```

If you need to really use an OR condition in order to perform the same action for two different conditions , you could do it also like this:

```
awk '/[*→]/{print a; a=$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
awk '/\*/ || /→/ {print}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the expected results you cite.  No need to escape the * because we can rely on the "In POSIX awk and gawk, the ‘*’, ‘+’, and ‘?’ operators stand for themselves when there is nothing in the regexp that precedes them." behaviour here, more details at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp

```
$ awk '/*/||/→/' file.txt
foo*
bar→
bar→
foo**
bar→
foo*
bar→
bar→
$
```

Using grep instead:

```
$ grep -E '\*|→' file.txt
```

Comment: Really?  `/*/` reads to me like "Zero or more characters of any type".

Comment: @DopeGhoti, GNU awk and GNU grep seem to accept that, though (matching a literal asterisk). `mawk` and Perl treat it as an error though. So probably better to escape it to make things clear.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I have never heard of any Regex engine interpreting it this way (quantifiers implying `.` as a token if there is none preceding). In fact I'm sure it would make things less, e.g. what about `x*+` or `x+?`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti - `/*/` in `awk` works.  Try it yourself.  `echo 'foo' | awk '/*/'` elicits no output.  While `echo 'foo*' | awk '/*/'` elicits output of 'foo*'.

Comment: @ilkkachu + @phk - have revised answer explain why `/*/` works